# Conversion from PHP to Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-4

I've been working on a project and this is what i wanna perform in laravel.

```
<?php 
require_once 'db.php';
$query = mysql_query("select distinct p.tag, p.tag2 from packages p order by 1") or       die(mysql_error());
while($object = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    $arr[] = $object;
}
echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Since i'm new to Laravel i don't know how to do it. I want my results to be as  following json format.

```
[{"tag":"Dubai","tag2":"U.A.E."},{"tag":"New York","tag2":"U.S.A."}]
```

I tried using Eloquent but failed. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do You gave SO far in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)

Your code in laravel will look similar to this:

```
$packages = DB::table('packages')->distinct()->select('tag', 'tag2')->get();

foreach ($packages as $package)
{
    var_dump($package->tag);
}

return Response::json($packages);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to include db file in laravel you just have to set database connections in app/config/database.php

After that if you want to get data/ select data you can use http://laravel.com/docs/quick quick guide here is everything you can learn..

Comment: Yes i already did that. What i mean to ask is how do i get the similar result using Eloquent. I want to use eloquent to perform the same task. But it returns something else instead of array of objects. Is there any short hand method to get the results as an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with Eloquent ORM in Laravel.  The Code may be as following;

In Model

```
class package extends Eloquent {}
```

In Controller or Route

```
$packages = Package::distinct()->select('tag', 'tag2')->get()->toJson();

return $packages;
```